# Change Names of Column after iterating over every column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the names of every column of my dataframe iterating over each column names

I am able to change the column names one by one but i want to use a for loop in order to change all column names

```
for i in range(0,len(flattened.columns)):
    flattened.rename(columns={flattened.columns[i]: "P" + str(i)})
```

Comment: `df.columns = "adfadf" + df.columns` should suffice

Comment: no i want to change the column names altogether and they must be in series:
P1, P2, P3.....etc

Comment: `flattened.columns = [f'P{i+1}' for i in range(len(flattened.columns))]` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create the dictionary for `rename` in a list comprehension and then apply it to all columns in a single step, like so:

```
flattened.rename(
    columns = {
        column_name: 'P' + str(index) for index,column_name in enumerate(flattened.columns)
    }
)
```

Is this what you are looking for?